# Fedora Gnome sudden high CPU usage

Tags: linux, operating-system

Suddenly my fedora gnome system starts lagging and acts extremely slow, When I open the system monitor, I see that one of the CPU threads is 100% working, but when I go to the processes section, no process is using more than 26 % of CPU,What are the possible causes and what do I have to consider?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use in a terminal the command :

> sudo htop

If the `htop` package is not present, don't hesitate to install it, it's pretty useful.

Please make sure you are running this command with root permissions : if you don't, you may not see some processes.
Then you can press F6 and sort processes by CPU percentage.

If you can't see anything, take a look at load average (given by htop) and see if it is normal (you may want to take a look at [this page](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages))

If you don't see anything special, you may be in a chroot or a container.